# Autopopulate sharepoint list field

Tags: list, javascript

Can anyone help me with auto populate of list field based on dropdown field.
Like i have list A with field Location(dropdown field). It has 10 values like India, Australia, UK, US etc. If anyone select India another testbox should get auto populate with data Delhi, for UK = London and so on.

Do I need to use any javascript and hardcode values in javascript?
can anyone provide me this script. Thanks

Comment: Are these pairs static or is this just a default value that the user can then change is needed? If this is static (India will always be Delhi and UK will always be London), you could just create a list with these values and have the lookup bring both values over. But right now it's hard to be sure exactly what you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186174/how-to-make-a-list-view-with-multiple-columns-from-single-lookup-column

Comment: I got below code but not sure which is dropdown field and which is text box(which need to auto populate)

Answer (score 2):

You could use javascript and read the appropriate values using the REST api.

I suggest an alternative -- create a term set with the locations specified in the appropriate hierarchy and use a Managed Metadata column on the list.